# Firebase onCompleteListener doesn't trigger when using RobolectricTestRunner

Tags: android, firebase, robolectric

I am using roboelectric to write some medium UI tests for the log-in flow but the on-complete-listener callback never gets called.

This is my test, the loginButton click is what calls the authentication. I'd added a ridiculously long wait (just in case!)

```
 new AsyncTask() {
     @Override
     protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
         loginButton.performClick();
         return null;
     } 
 }.execute();

 ShadowApplication.runBackgroundTasks();
 Thread.sleep(100000);
 Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler();
```

This is how I'm calling Firebase

```
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
 .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             log("sign in successful")
         }
         else {
             log("sign in failed..")
         }
     }
 });
```

I have initialized the FirebaseApp in my android application class as follows

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
     FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
             .setApplicationId("######")
             .setApiKey("#####")
             .setDatabaseUrl("https://###.firebaseio.com")
             .build();
     FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(), options);
 }
```

There are the versions I'm using

- firebaseVersion =  '10.0.1'
- robolectric =  '3.5.1'

Note that I have included this in my build.gradle:app
`compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$firebaseVersion"`

I've been reading SO posts and blogs for the last 5 hours with no luck, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would abstract firebase and mock it in tests

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @EugenMartynov but that didn't work for me wither. I used power-mock to mock firebase and there were two issues. Firstly, it was extremely verbose with all the child() and dbReferences() being queried everywhere. Secondly, and more importantly, I couldn't get the power-mock to mock the static FirebaseApp.getInstance().

Comment: I didn't say PowerMock :) I would remove firebase coupling from the activity, has own Auth component, inject it and mock it in tests.